# JAVA: Creating new objects that don't interfere with other objects of same class

Tags: java, oop, object, new-operator

I'm new here (also new to programming) and I tried to look for an answer but couldn't come up with one. My assignment is due today so help would be very appreciated. This problem has happened to me twice, but the first I was able to ignore it by programming another way now I can't anymore. Every time I create a new object `(Agent a = new Agent() <-- name of my class)`,     it interferes with other objects of same type (does this have anything to do with reference types?). I'm trying to make a `DiscussionDirector` `class`    that takes two Agent objects and creates a randomized conversation between them (Random based), but I can't even get started because I haven't been able to create two objects of type Agent yet.

Here's the code for Agent:

```
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Random;

public class Agent{
  private static boolean isMale;
  private static String birthdate;
  private static int birthyear;
  private static int birthmonth;
  private static int birthday;
  private static String name;
  private static String nativeCity;
  private static String currentCity;
  private static String major;
  private static Random r = new Random();

  public static void main(String[]args){
  }

  public String getCityNow(){
    return this.currentCity;
  }

  public String getCityBorn(){
    return this.nativeCity;
  }

  public String getName(){
    return this.name;
  }

  public boolean getGender(){
    return this.isMale;
  }

  public String getMajor(){
    return this.major;
  }

  public String getBirthday(){
    String birthdate = (this.birthday + "/" + this.birthmonth + "/" + this.birthyear);
    return birthdate;
  }
  public void sayHelloTo(String name){
    System.out.println(this.name + " says: Hi " + name + ", I'm " + this.name);
  }

  public void sayHello(){
    System.out.println(this.name + " says: Hello, my name is " + this.name);
  }

  public void CityBorn(){
    System.out.println(this.name + " says: I am from " + this.nativeCity);
  }

  public void howOldAreYou(){
    System.out.print(this.name + " says: I am ");
    if(Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.MONTH) < this.birthmonth){
      System.out.println((Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.YEAR) - this.birthyear - 1) + " years old");
    }
    else if((Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.MONTH) == this.birthmonth) && (Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) == this.birthday)){
      System.out.println((Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.YEAR) - this.birthyear - 1) + " years old");
    }
    else{
      System.out.println((Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.YEAR) - this.birthyear) + " years old");
    }

  }

  public void sayGender(){
    System.out.println(this.name + " says: I am a ");
    if(isMale == true){
      System.out.print("man");
    }
    else{
      System.out.print("woman");
    }
  }

  public void CityNow(){
    System.out.println(this.name + " says: I currently live in " + this.currentCity);
  }

  public void sayMajor(){
    System.out.println(this.name + " says: I am studying " + this.major);
  }

  public void whoAreYou(){
    sayHello();
    CityBorn();
    howOldAreYou();
    sayMajor();
    CityNow();
  }

  public Agent()throws IOException{
    this.isMale = r.nextBoolean();
    if(this.isMale == true){
      WordList MaleNames = new WordList("MaleNames.txt");
      this.name = MaleNames.getRandomWord();
    }
    else{
      WordList FemaleNames = new WordList("FemaleNames.txt");
      this.name = FemaleNames.getRandomWord();
    }
    this.birthyear = 1995 - r.nextInt(60); //Agents can't be too young or too old.
    this.birthmonth = r.nextInt(11)+1;
    if(this.birthmonth == 1|this.birthmonth == 3|this.birthmonth == 5|this.birthmonth == 7|this.birthmonth == 8|this.birthmonth == 10|this.birthmonth == 12){
      this.birthday = r.nextInt(30)+1;
    }
    else if (this.birthmonth == 2){
      this.birthday = r.nextInt(27)+1;
    }
    else{
      this.birthday = r.nextInt(29)+1;
    }
    WordList Major = new WordList("Majors.txt");
    this.major = Major.getRandomWord();
    WordList Cities = new WordList("Cities.tx");
    this.nativeCity = Cities.getRandomWord();
    this.currentCity = Cities.getRandomWord();
  }

  public Agent generateAgent()throws IOException{
    return new Agent();
  }

}
```

So yeah, does anyone have any idea why when I create a two `Agent()` objects and then do `generateAgent()`     objects on them, they're always the same?

Thanks

Comment: it's because you declared all the object variables as static, only use static if you wish for the variable value to be preserved across all instances of your class.  Looking at your class briefly, you should not statically assign any of those variables except possibly `Random r`.

Answer (score 5):

You've made all your class variables `static`, which means one copy for the whole class.  Remove `static` on all of them, so they all have one value per object instance.

Answer (score 0):

This is because all fields are declared static in your agent class. 
A static field is shared among all instances of the class.
To solve your issue just remove the static keyword!

Answer (score 0):

A typical use of static keyword inside a class is a counter of created instances of that class.

```
    public class Agent{
      private static int numberAgent;
      private String birthdate;
      private int birthyear;
      private int birthmonth;
      ...
    }
```

And in the constructors of the class, you do
numberAgent++;

As the static variable of a class are shared across all the instances of the class,
you will have the number of agents instanciated in all Agent objects.